# How to associate additional data to files in files-upload form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, laravel

I'm creating a file-upload section on my website where I want to add additional data to each document (fie) that is about to be uploaded to the server.

I want to associate each file with a list of users and to add a description of it. Then, on my server side (PHP, Laravel) I want to be able
to understand that "*somefile.pdf*" is related to (for example) "Josh", and "Dan" and its description would be (for example) "Some description about the file", and that "anotherfile.pdf" is related to another list of users and has another description.

Here's a form for example: (*It is really ugly, sorry about that, it's only an example*)

```js
updateList = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('files');
    var output = document.getElementById('fileList');

    output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        output.innerHTML += '<li><strong>' + input.files.item(i).name + "</strong>" ;
        output.innerHTML += `<select multiple>
                                <option value="Josh">Josh</option>
                                <option value="George">George</option>
                                <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
                                <option value="Clark">Clark</option>
                            </select>
                            Description: <input type="text"></li>`
    }
    output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}
```

```html
<form class="col-lg-6" action="/documents" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onchange="javascript:updateList()">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <br>
    Choose Documents (can attach more than one):
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="documents[]" id="files" multiple />
    <br />
    <div id="fileList"></div>
    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I tried to iterate the files before they submitted to the server and then add 2 new attributes to each of them, like this:

```
input.files[0].description = "Some description about the file";
input.files[0].users = ["Josh", "Dan"];
```

I wasn't sure if something like this is even possible, and indeed - it doesn't work.

I tried several other things but on the server side, I wasn't able to understand which description and users belong to which file.

I'm searching for the cleanest, efficient and user-friendly way to submit these files along with the associated data, and on my Laravel application, I want to be able to handle this data easily so I can add the information to my database tables.

Comment: Do you have a predefined list of users?

Comment: I'll retrieve it from the server dynamically and pass it to the view. The multi-select box will be generated dynamically with users, and the uploader will choose which file to associate with whom.

Comment: well, can you add a column to the users table with an id of some sort and sort by it after you populate it in the view and send it to the server upon upload?

Comment: I don't believe this is necessary